# Custom expanding/collapsing Date Picker expands off view when it's in the bottom cell of table view - Swift

Tags: swift, uidatepicker, uianimation

I have a custom inline date picker that expands and collapses just like the Apple Calendar events date pickers. The problem is that I need the Date Picker to in a UITableViewCell that is at the bottom of the UITableView, but when it expands, you cannot see the Picker without scrolling the view down manually. For a similar issue (UITextField disappears behind keyboard when it's being edited if it's below the height of the keyboard) I was able to fix it with an animation in the beginEditing and endEditing delegate functions:

```
let keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 216

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.25, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
   self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.origin.y - keyboardHeight), self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
}, completion: nil)
```

Does anyone know of a similar animation that would work for maybe placing in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and if it's a date picker the screen will adjust by scrolling down to show the full date picker expanded, and then it will adjust back when the row is not selected anymore - or something along these lines?

- I'm not sure if the fact that there's already an animation occurring to expand/collapse the date picker would conflict with this or if it's just a matter of precedence for the animations to occur. Anyways I will post some code below:

When the DatePicker is selected in the tableView:

```
/**
  Used to notify the DatePickerCell that it was selected. The DatePickerCell will then run its selection animation and expand or collapse.
  */
    public func selectedInTableView() {
        expanded = !expanded

        UIView.transitionWithView(rightLabel, duration: 0.25, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.rightLabel.textColor = self.expanded ? self.tintColor : self.rightLabelTextColor
            }, completion: nil)
    }
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        // Deselect automatically if the cell is a DatePickerCell.
        let cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

        if (cell.isKindOfClass(DatePickerCell)) {

            let datePickerTableViewCell = cell as! DatePickerCell
            datePickerTableViewCell.selectedInTableView()
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if(cell.isKindOfClass(PickerCell)) {

                let pickerTableViewCell = cell as! PickerCell
                pickerTableViewCell.selectedInTableView()
                tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        }

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with a solution that seems to work as needed, I wrote this code in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate function after the call to `selectedInTablView()`:

```
if(datePickerTableViewCell.isExpanded() && datePickerTableViewCell.datePicker == billDatePicker.datePicker) {
            tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height + datePickerTableViewCell.datePickerHeight())
}
```